# URL issue when running Symfony on production mode

Tags: symfony

I have just uploaded my Symfony 3 project on my web server. The root directory of my Symfony project does not include a index.php file. So calling `www.example.com` won't work but when I go to `www.example.com/web` my website can be displayed.

How can I get rid of that `/web` in the URL?

Comment: Who downvoted? It's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your full path in your web server should include the path to the `web` subdirectory. There is no `index.php` that is used.

Comment: I just thought I would need to change something in the configuration or use .htaccess but that was really a quick solution. Thank you!

Comment: Like @LeMenachFlorian mentions, `app.php` is used, but you don't ever enter that in a browser. You might use `app_dev.php` for debugging.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to route a Symfony application to a domain name, your domain's vHost configuration will do the job. root **/app/web; index app.php;**

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2 (or Symfony3) does not use an index.php file but an web/**app.php** (production environment) and web/**app_dev.php** (development environment) entry.